# NavigationRail or NavigationDrawer subItems

Tags: flutter

How can my application work like Material 3 Design regarding `NavigationRail`?

If you open the material 3 website for flutter you can check that when a navigation item has a submenum it opens a new container on the right with the the subitems organized as `ListTiles` like but with new Material Design.

https://m3.material.io/develop/flutter

Notice that it has three behaviors:

1. When the browser is in full width (Submenu items is always there)
2. When the browser is in medium width (Submenu items only shows when selecting navigation rail)
3. When the browser is in small width (no `NavigationRail` and a `NavigationDrawer` is created)

Can I achieve that with default flutter widgets? I've `NavigationRail` or `NavigationDrawer` without success.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationRail` will be the closest to what you can achieve with the default flutter widgets.

You will have to create custom widget by yourself to have the exact same behavior or any behavior that come close to it.